# I want to set priority of product in category-> product view

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I want to show products with **$0 price** on last.
I am trying to make changes in file
`app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

> if($_product->price==0):

but can't do it and don't know how to do it. Please anyone tell me how can i do it.

Comment: Elaborate your question. What you want to do? Show $0 on last? What last?

Comment: @ali zaki thanks to give ma a chance to improve my question.
i have products that price is $0. but i don't want to show on first priority.
i want to display $0 products of the last priority

Comment: i want to display $0 price product at the End of  all products

Comment: You can set position to that product for particular category from admin.

Comment: thanks  @ prathmeshb but i want to do it dynamically with programming

Comment: I am not getting why you are changing in View.phtml file. If you want to sort product based on product price then try to achieve by altering product collection

Comment: $Gopal Patel so please can You suggest me how and which file i have to do work ? to do this

Comment: @Grace on which page you want to sort collection?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog->Manage Categories` select a category then go to **Category Products** Tab and set position of product i.e. 1, 2 3 4 etc as you like, on frontend product will display according to your position set i.e 1 will display first and so on.

Comment: you can Accept my answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: i would like to do it with programming  i haven't  need to  go again and again in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

1. You need do 2 change one is go to admin -> system -> Configuration -> Catalog there in tab Front end you find **'Product Listing Sort by'** select price and save config.
2. Copy

   `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List`

and copy file Toolbar.php and put

```
app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List
```

then change one line

```
protected $_direction           = 'asc'; to protected $_direction = 'desc';
```